# Populating Listbox with data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005-express

I don't know what is happening to my program, it took me (4) four minutes to load the result of my code.... can someone tell me why? Can someone tell me how to fix this loading problem?

This is my code:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim str As String = "Data Source=######;Initial Catalog=###;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=#####;Password=#####"
        Dim con As New SqlConnection(str)
        Dim cmd As String = "Select ControlNo,EmpNo,CheckOutDate,CheckOutTime,TaxiNo,PlateNo,Model,Make from dbo.ChkInOut"
        Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(com, con)
        Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
        adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "dbo.ChkInOut")
        Dim myDataTable As DataTable = myDataSet.Tables(0)
        Dim tempRow As DataRow
        For Each tempRow In myDataTable.Rows
            'ListBox1.Items.Add((tempRow("ControlNo") & " (" & tempRow("EmpNo") & ")" & " (" & tempRow("CheckOutDate") & ")" & " (" & tempRow("CheckOutTime") & ")" & " (" & tempRow("TaxiNo") & ")" & " (" & tempRow("PlateNo") & ")" & " (" & tempRow("Model") & ")" & " (" & tempRow("Make") & ")"))
            'ListBox1.Items.Add((tempRow("ControlNo") & " (" & tempRow("EmpNo") & ")"))
            ListBox1.Items.Add(tempRow("ControlNo") & "            " & tempRow("EmpNo") & "            " & tempRow("CheckOutDate") & "            " & tempRow("CheckOutTime") & "            " & tempRow("TaxiNo") & "            " & tempRow("PlateNo") & "            " & tempRow("Model") & "            " & tempRow("Make") & "            ")
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What is the size of table ChkInOut ? total rows ?

Comment: Code looks fine - could be *slightly* improved by declaring a `DataTable` (instead of `DataSet`) and fill that data table, since you only ever needs one single table - but that's not going to make a huge difference.... was there a lot of other activity on the server at this point in time? Was that table e.g. locked by a large `INSERT` statement or something like that?

Comment: @Behroz - it's quite large, 188,874 rows that is the total rows

Comment: @marc_s how to use that DataTable that your talking about?

Comment: @Danjor: added an answer to show how to use a `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`

Comment: @marc_s I don't know how to use it , honestly speaking I just used this codes that I got from some website and I apply it, but first I just tried it with 1 button and 1 listbox to know if it's working, and I found out that it is working but the problem is the loading of my program.

Comment: So, clearly you have alot of rows. For each row, you are using a loop and concatenating string. It will take time. You should return the concatenated string from the query and bind the results directly to the listbox.

Comment: @Behroz like I said I don't have any idea on how to do that kind of command , could you help me?

Comment: you need a WHERE clause in your SQL - as it stands at the moment you are returning the whole table

Comment: @peterG is absolutely right, you need to limit the dataset. A Listbox with > 200 records starts becoming unusable. if the dataset is > 180,000 you're doing everything  wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

firstly, I must agree with the above question, how much data is being returned.
In addition to that, can I suggest that rather than looping through the DataTable and populating the ListBox, you rather bind the data:

```
Dim myDataSet As New DataSet()
adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "dbo.ChkInOut")

ListBox1.DataTextField = "yourtext"
ListBox1.DataValueField = "yourvalue"
ListBox1.Datasource = myDataSet
ListBox1.DataBind()
```

This might just increase the performance.

Comment: error occured :
'dataTextField' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox'

Answer (score 4):

apologies... thought is was a web application.

Try this:

```
ListBox1.DataSource = myDataTable 
ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ColumnName"
```

Comment: I tried it, it works but the problem is I want to display all the column to the ListBox1 so I tried to put it this way:

ListBox1.DisplayMember = "ControlNo,EmpNo,CheckOutDate,CheckOutTime,TaxiNo,PlateNo,Model,Make"

and there is a display message in ListBox1 'System.Data.DataRowView'

Comment: I tried to used atleast 2 columns it shows the same message, can you help me what to do about it?

Comment: in your SQL query, build up a column of all the values. then, use that column for this. 

e.g. 
SELECT
  blah1,
  blah2,
  blah1 + ' ' + blah2 as FinalBlah
FROM
  tablename

then use FinalBlah as your value for the listbox - make sense?

Comment: wahh! it's hard to understand! what is the 'blah!' 'blah!' :(

Comment: SELECT col1, col2, col1 + ' ' + col2 as FinalCol FROM tablename. This help?

Comment: what actually the ' ' for? is there a textbox in there?

Comment: what i was doing there is concatenating the fields together, and the ' ' is to add a space between the two columns values, similar to the "     " you had in your original code that you pasted.

Comment: it works! how to make a space on listbox? because the output was 120129960606385

12012996 - was in 1st col
0606385 - was in 2nd col
how to make a space between to make it look good and for easy viewing?

Comment: I get it now, thanks to you sir! if I can only add some reputation for you I would gladly do it... thank you for lots of help!

Comment: wait I have one last question : how to fix this one?

>>> Syntax error converting datetime from character string

the error comes from :

adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "dbo.ChkInOut")

Comment: ah. that is a DB conversion issue. Try converting the value to string like: CONVERT(varchar, ColumnName, 110)

Comment: am I gonna change it to SQL SERVER? or in the DATASET only?

Comment: is there a sql string for that? or a command something like that?

Comment: in your SQL query, where you concat the columns together, perferom the CONVERT there... like SELECT Col1 + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, Col2, 110) FROM TableName - if Col2 is your date field

Comment: Ok thanks , Im newbie to SQLSERVER and to the string etc. sorry for that! your really a big help to this site :)